# How to override ruby Net::ReadTimeout value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently using `HTTParty` as http request tool to perform `curl` operations.

But every time I trigger some requests like POST/GET, the response time is not fast enough to process all information and raise `500 Internal errors`.

Any methods for me to override the default value of `Net::ReadTimeout`? Because the Net lib is wrapped into the HTTParty lib.

Comment: How did you handle this? I am having the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'timeout'
TIMEOUT = 10 # seconds

begin
  Timeout::timeout(TIMEOUT) do
    # your http call
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  # handle http call timed out
end
```

Comment: require 'timeout'
      # TIMEOUT = 10000000 # seconds

      begin
        Timeout::timeout(1000) do
          puts res = CalDAV_API.http_request(:get, '/user/1/caldav/hihi/fa176fde-186e-4f05-8fdd-582dcb8d5f15.ics')
          puts 'res.body'
          puts res.body, res.code, res.message, res.headers.inspect
        end
      rescue Timeout::Error
        # handle http call timed out
        puts 'really timeout'
      end

Comment: What do you mean @GeorgeJor? It that your code? If that a further question? Does the work or not?